# How to ask input from user in C using pointers and character

Tags: c, pointers, input, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *p;

    printf("User:- Please write about my self here --> \n");
    scanf("%s",p);
    //Case 1
    printf("The o/p of first persion is here -->>\n %s",p);
    //This gives output as (null) Can you please tell why it's happening

    // Case 2
    printf("\n The op here is -->> %p\n",p);
    //This gives op as (nil)
}
```

Can you please explain to me or drop some links for pointer it's my first time on Stack and pointers
Thanks in advance.[Refer to case 1, 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVZ2l.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for basic research and study. Reading user input will be covered in any good C book/tutorial and searching for examples should bring up many results.

Comment: You certainly can ask basic questions. But after doing reasonable research and self learning first. Basic questions in particular will usually already be answered or explained somewhere. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `p` to point to. You need `p = malloc(BUFSIZE);`

Answer (score 0):

It is giving null because you not initilized p, you not gave it any address to point. You just declared it. Use malloc() or give it the address of another array of char.

```
char array[nindex];
p = array;
As array stores address of first element

Or you malloc()
p = malloc(size);
```